# How to redirect in react-router when routes are in different files

Tags: reactjs, react-routing

I was trying to redirect to the login page if the user is not logged in. It was working fine when I was using routes in App.js but after making seperate file for routing I am not.

route.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './Login';
import Register from './Register';
import Home from './Home';
import './style.css';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const routes = (
        <Switch>
            <Route key="0" path="/" exact render={ props => <Home {...props} />} />
            <Route key="1" path="/login" render={ props => <Login {...props} />} />
            <Route key="2" path="/register" render={ props => <Register {...props} />}  />
            <Route key="2" path="/home"  render={ props => <Home {...props} /> } />
        </Switch>
        );

export default routes;
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  state={
    isLogin:false
  }
  render() {
    return (

      <div className="App">
      <Router>
      <Header/>
    <div className="container">
      {routes}

    </div>
    </Router>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My previous rout conditions was

```
const routes = (
           <Switch>
            <Route key="0" path="/" exact render={ () => this.state.login ? ( <Home/> ): ( <Redirect to="/login"/> )} />} />
            <Route key="1" path="/login" render={ props => <Login {...props} />} />
            <Route key="2" path="/register" render={ props => <Register {...props} />}  />
            <Route key="2" path="/home"  render={ () => this.state.login ? ( <Home/> ): ( <Redirect to="/login"/> )} />
          </Switch>
        );
```

SO I want these routes to be working.

Comment: nothing wrong just you need to import the  `routes `
and the import that in app.js import Routes from './route' 
and the use <Routes> <Header/><Routes/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small sandbox to show you how to do it, we create routes as a function that takes in the `isLogin` state from `App` and based on that value we render the right component.

```
const Home = () => <h1>Home</h1>;
const Login = () => <h1>Login</h1>;
const Register = () => <h1>Register</h1>;

const Nav = () => (
  <div>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
    <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
  </div>
);
// Takes isLogged from this.state
const routes = isLogged => (
  <Switch>
    <Route
      path="/"
      exact
      render={() => (isLogged ? <Home /> : <Redirect to="/login" />)}
    />
    } />
    <Route path="/login" render={props => <Login {...props} />} />
    <Route path="/register" render={props => <Register {...props} />} />
    <Route
      path="/home"
      render={() => (isLogged ? <Home /> : <Redirect to="/login" />)}
    />
  </Switch>
);

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isLogin: false
  };

  toggleLogin = () =>
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isLogin: !prevState.isLogin
    }));

  render() {
    const { isLogin } = this.state;

    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <button onClick={this.toggleLogin}>Toggle Login</button>
          <Nav />
          <h1>{`isLogin ${isLogin}`}</h1>
          {/* invoke routes with isLogin */}
          {routes(isLogin)}
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

[SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l26ko5y0jq)